# iOS: Playing embed code videos within the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, webview, youtube

I am working on an app in which i have to display videos comes from `JSON` server some of them are `youtube` video and some are from other resources.
My problem is when i want to play video the videos which are from youtube link are playing perfectly but the other videos are not playing.
i imported  `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>, <AVKit/AVKit.h>, MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h` files also i imported `YTPlayerView` Files

I am using following code in `UIWebView`

```
[self.webvw setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
    [self.webvw setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];

    NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",videoStr];
    [self.webvw loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

The other video format is look like as:

```
"embed_code": "<object width="430" height="344"><embed width="430" height="344" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" src="http://xxxxxxx.xxxxxx/static/jscript/player/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf?config={'clip':{'baseUrl': 'http://myconnect.media/file/video/','url': '2017/02/3d045f0f240bfb73305f77c3da4d9218.flv','autoBuffering': true,'autoPlay': false}}"></embed></object>"
```

Comment: Add code, what you did so far.

Comment: @Abhinandan how can the sample json data can play video on native iOS, its flash content meant for web and the web too might not be able to play this due to flash content is not supported, please check the youtube player api and implementation ways it require. More code is required to understand your approach.

Comment: @DevanshuSaini: how can i convert that flash content into a supported format?

Comment: Sorry you have to manually convert somewhere else say ffmpeg command. Its the responsibility of server, iOS app won't do it.
In my earlier project the available content from source was flash, so our server triggered one method to convert to mp4 file (with specs specified by apple) and provide mp4 file url to the iOS app.

Comment: @ImadAli i added my code